# String replace PHP from a TEXT field within MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the following in my database which stores as JSON and are images that I want to then display but I'm not sure on how to do a string replace to get rid of the [ " , and spaces and just grab the random string.png

```
["4a21da2670ce6528b2cffebf6f42cb1b8ade3c13.png","4d9465c0694079296b24f6e3be7b226eaa9f94dd.png"]
```

Above is what I get from my DB so how would one string replace this.

I have tried:

```
<img src="/uploads/products/'. str_replace("[", "", $pieces[$i]).'" width="35">
```

But to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not str_replace json, you json_decode it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$json = '["4a21da2670ce6528b2cffebf6f42cb1b8ade3c13.png","4d9465c0694079296b24f6e3be7b226eaa9f94dd.png"]';
$array = json_decode($json);

foreach($array as $a) {
    echo '<img src="/uploads/products/'.$a.'" width="35">';
}
```

This will output

```
<img src="/uploads/products/4a21da2670ce6528b2cffebf6f42cb1b8ade3c13.png" width="35">
<img src="/uploads/products/4d9465c0694079296b24f6e3be7b226eaa9f94dd.png" width="35">
```

([See example](http://3v4l.org/qIPNV))